# El recurso requerido no está disponible. Tomcat 10, Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

soy nuevo en este framework y también en este servidor. Instale Tomcat y la extensión para usar Spring en visual studio code. Pero, al intentar acceder a mi drectorio me dice que no lo encuentra.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este pequeño archivo para verificar de que se esté ejecutando en el servidor, pero nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo está perfecto, al parecer.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi directorio es demo, ahí aparece. Pero, al querer acceder a él dice que el recurso no está disponible.

Comment: Para futuras preguntas el código debe ir siembre en `texto` y no en imagen, porque dificulta la lectura y la modificación para  utilizar tú código en  las respuestas, también en imagen es menos probable que recibas una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando la información que muestras, los errores que presentas son `@RequestMapping("/")` es una anotación que debe de ir sobre la `Clase HolaMundo` para definir el la ruta base de l servicio rest, el segundo error es que en un servicio `REST` tienes las acciones `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` en el caso del servicio `hola` debe de ser anotado con `@GetMapping` para que la ruta sea `/` pero si quieres que la ruta sea `/hola` se debe de anotar `@GetMapping("hola")`.